# Prevent plugin activation and add admin notice

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I'm working on a plugin that needs to create a CSV file upon it's activation.
I want to notice the user if for some reason the file couldn't be open, and prevent the plugin's activation.
Here's my code so far:

```
public static function hcg_create_csv_file(){
    try {
        $file_name = self::FILE_NAME;
        $fields    = self::get_csv_head_fields();

        $file = fopen( HCG_ABSPATH . 'src/' . $file_name, 'w' );
        if ( ! $file ) {
            throw new Exception(__('Failed to open CSV file, please check your directory permissions.', ''));
        }

        fputcsv( $file, $fields );
        fclose( $file );

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $GLOBAL['hcg_activation_error_msg'] = $e->getMessage();
        deactivate_plugins( basename( __FILE__ ) );
        $redirect_url = add_query_arg('hcg_activation_error_msg', 1, admin_url('plugins.php'));
        wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

And the activation hook ("Hashavshevet_CSV_Generator" is the name of the  main plugin class"):

```
register_activation_hook( HCG_PLUGIN_FILE, array('Hashavshevet_CSV_Generator', 'hcg_create_csv_file') );
```

As you can see what I've tried to do in this function in case of an error is to refresh the page with a new url parameter which will indicate there is an error, also I put the error message in a global variable so I will be able to access it from the `admin_notices()` function, here's the fuction hooked to `admin_notices()`:

```
function hcg_add_admin_error_msg(){
    if ( isset($_GET['hcg_activation_error_msg']) ) {
        global $hcg_activation_error_msg;
        $class   = 'notice notice-error';

        printf( '<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', esc_attr( $class ), esc_html( $hcg_activation_error_msg ) );
    }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'hcg_add_admin_error_msg');
```

The problem is because the plugin is not activate, this function don't run, as it located (and should be located) in the plugin file.

Any idea how to go around this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: please do not bump questions. this questions was answered before, and as you say yourself it is impossible, end of story.

Comment: If I thought it was impossible I would not ask the question, there's nothing impossible. all the solutions I saw wasn't good enough..